# Mercurial - who made this clone?

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to know who is the user who made a new repository (cloned)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of. Cloning is a read only operation, there's no write access to the repo and no writes happen on the cloned version. There may be methods outside of Mercurial though such as file permission settings or bash histories.

Comment: Thx Paystey. I was hoping that as the parent repository is written as a value in the .hg/hgrc, a user value is written somewhere...